# Use VueJs local file instead of importing it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been learning VueJs through single file application at the first start.

It would consist in a single `html` page containing my `javascript` & `CSS` style within.

In order not to import the VueJs features from the web I have downloaded the `Vue.JS` file and linked it into the `HTML` file by inputing:

```
<head>
...
<script src="vue.js"
...
</head>
```

By doing this I was able to add a `<script>...</script>` into my `HTML` file, that consists in the `JS` code that would recognize `Vue`.

It worked just fine.

Now I want to split the code into their respective files:

- `HTML` file
- `JS` file
- `CSS` file

Now I am confused to what should I import at the `<head>` section of my HTML file, as I need to import my `file.js` that contains my code + I will want to have my `Vue.js` file running so I don't need to import `vue.js` from the web.

What should I do?

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
<head>
<title>First Vue playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Below is my JS code-->
    <script src="appJS.js"></script> 
   <!-- below is my vue.js file so it runs Vue locally instead of importing it-->
   <scrip src="vue.js"></scrip>
</head>
```

It's a basic question as it is my first time doing this.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Put the `<scrip src="vue.js"></scrip>` before your `script src="appJS.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried it and it does not work. Please check out how is my ```<head>``` tag: ```<head> <title>First Vue playground</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <script src="vue.js"></script> <script src="appJS.js"></script> </head> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use Vue in the file appJS.js, you will need to first import the vue.js before your file. here is how your files should look like :

**App.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'hello vue'
        }
    });
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="./scripts/vue.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
<title>Vue Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried it and it does not work. Please check out how is my ```<head>``` tag: ```<head>
    <title>First Vue playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="appJS.js"></script>
</head>```

Comment: I am using WebStorm

Comment: Can you share the console output

Comment: How do I do that? When I split the files and run the app ```CSS``` is recognized, but ```Vue``` simply does not work. In other words, the page gets static and the curly braces become visible inside the ```html``` tags.

Comment: @Alioshr I just added a working example. I hope that helps

Comment: It does not work... Thanks anyway. I don't understand why it is so hard to split files in VueJs

Comment: can you share what you see on the console?